# makestyles is not working nextsjs material ui version 5

Tags: css, material-ui, next.js

I am using nextjs with material ui

```
"@mui/material": "^5.0.1",
"@mui/styles": "^5.0.1",
```

and here is my component

```
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, Box, Button, Link } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const Navbar = () => {

  const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    navItem: {
      color: "white"
    }
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
              MyCode
            </Typography>


            <Typography variant="h6" component="div">
              <Link className={classes.navItem} href="/blog">Blog</Link>
            </Typography>

            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>

          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

I have created this navbar with a blog nav item and with login button.

Blog nav item is not visible on the screen as the color it inherit the color of background of nav bar.

So I added some classes by using `makeStyles` and created a `navItem` class with `color:white`

It shows the class on the DOM on html but this is not visible in `Styles` section, so color is not white.

what can be the issue?

Comment: Put the `useStyles` declaration outside of the functional component.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `useStyles` outside your functional component. In this case you don't need use `makeStyles`. Just:

```
<Link color="white" />
```

Comment: I created useStyles outside the Navvar(), but still it is not working